# Electric field energy density

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electric-fields

In vacuum, the energy density of the electric field is given by $\mathcal{E}=\epsilon_0\frac{E^2}{2}$ with $E$ the total electric field present. So, if you have a static $E_0$ and dynamic $e(t)$ field, the energy density becomes
$$\mathcal{E}=\epsilon_0\frac{\left[E_0+e(t)\right]^2}{2} = \epsilon_0\frac{E_0^2 +2E_0e(t)+e(t)^2}{2}\,.$$

Is this correct? What does the term $2E_0e(t)$ physically represent? It looks like an additional energy contribution from the interaction between the two fields...

Answer (score 3):

The cross term represents interference. It is the term that makes it so that the energy density is reduced when the two fields are in opposite directions and so that the energy density is increased when the two fields are in the same direction.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. Note however that, when dealing with periodic electric fields, one would often be interested in the energy density averaged over a period, where the cross-term disappears:
$$e(t) = E_1\cos(\omega t),\\
\bar{\mathcal{E}} = \frac{\omega}{2\pi}\int_{t_0}^{t_0 + 2\pi/\omega}dt \frac{\epsilon_0|E_0 + E_1\cos (\omega t)|^2}{2} = \frac{\epsilon_0E_0^2}{2} + \frac{\epsilon_0 E_1^2}{4}
$$

The general expression for the energy density can be rigorously obtained from the Maxwell equations within the context of the *Pointing theorem*.

Comment: Can this term that disappears in the integral be seen as reactive energy/power?

Comment: Indeed, this is a possible interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct. I don't think there is any special interpretation of the cross term, it's just a contribution to the energy density.